# how to get selected row IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How do I know which row is currently selected in table view without using any global variable to store last clicked row using this method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a global variable.  *if* you need to track the currently selected row, you can create a member variable (iVar) in the class that is the delegate for the table view callbacks.

That method passes you the indexPath which has the row that was selected.  If you want remember that for other function callbacks, then create a property or iVar in that class.

In header:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSInteger _selectedRow;
}
```

In implementation

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   _selectedRow = indexPath.row;
}
```

Comment: Any other way other than storing in extra variable, IOS is memory constraint right..

Comment: Yes, the device is memory constrained but you're talking about one variable that's not a function of the number of rows.  It's exactly one variable (an int) for the one table.  *If* you need to remember the selected row beyond the scope of this function, you can't do it any lighter than a single int variable.  That's the size of the data you're trying to remember.

Comment: nonono... this won't work if you have multiple sections in your table.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the UITableView in an outlet property, you can get the selected row like this:

```
[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
```

which will return an indexPath containing row and section numbers of the selected row.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Store in NSUserDefault

In this delegate method u can get Currently Selected Row Add int curRowIndex in .h file

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  curRowIndex = indexPath.row
  NSLog(@"Currently Selected Row: %d",curRowIndex);
}
```

Comment: That's doesn't allow you to remember the selected row beyond the scope of that function - only to access it within that callback function.  If you want the *last* selected row (not the current) you need to store it somewhere.

Comment: Its looks working for me now. If any problem comes I will store as guys said.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this way ....

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Using Indexpath I got row.

Answer (score 1):

If your table contains more that one section then you have to track the section also.
For that you have to create an object of `NSIndexPath`.

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSIndexPath *obj_IndexPath;
}
```

and in implementation file,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
       obj_IndexPath = indexPath;

       NSLog(@"%d",obj_IndexPath.row);
       NSLog(@"%d",obj_IndexPath.section);

}
```

and don't forget to `release` `obj_IndexPath` in `dealloc` method

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
   // do something...
  }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
   // do something else ...
 }
```